# Force error when lcov code coverage is not above threshold

Tags: cmake, code-coverage, lcov

I have a c++ project that uses CMake for generating makefiles. I have added a custom target to run the code coverage as follows:

```
    add_custom_target(
      coverage
      COMMAND
        lcov --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 --capture --directory
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} --output-file
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_coverage.info --no-external
      COMMAND
        genhtml --branch-coverage
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_coverage.info --output-directory
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/coverage_report --title
        "${PROJECT_NAME} code coverage report" --show-details --legend
      COMMAND
        echo
        "Covverage report in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/coverage_report/index.html")
```

(earlier in the project I set the right compilation and linking flags and add different tests using `add_test`). When I run `make`, `make test`, `make coverage` I get the code coverage report properly. Now I am integrating this into a CI/CD and I want to check the coverage % of the resulting code coverage analysis to be above a threshold. If it is not above I want to fail the pipeline. Is there a way to run some process that will exit with an error code if the coverage is not above a given threshold?

Comment: Not sure what the format of the `.info` file is, but it it's a text file with reasonably simple structure, you may be able to use a cmake script file to check the values and simply use `message(FATAL_ERROR ...)` in that script, if it's to low...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the coverage from `lcov` to `gcovr` solves this issue. `gcovr` has [`--fail-under-line <min>`](https://gcovr.com/en/stable/manpage.html#cmdoption-gcovr-fail-under-line) and [`--fail-under-branch <min>`](https://gcovr.com/en/stable/manpage.html#cmdoption-gcovr-fail-under-branch) options that will make the program exit with an error code (2 and 4 respectively) if the min is not reached (min is in the range 0-100).